# Cache behaviour of std::vector

Tags: c++

My question is simple enough, given the following data structure, `std::vector<std::pair<int, std::unique_ptr<foo>>>`, if I have the following:

```
auto it = std::find_if(begin(v), end(v), [&](std::pair<...> const& p){ return p.first == some_value; });
```

Can I expect that whatever is pointed to by the pointer is not fetched (I don't want it fetched, will later pre-fetch as needed) into the cache purely for the find operation? Or is this impossible to determine (if so I will close the question..)

Comment: I don't see any pointer in your example...

Comment: @J99, there is a `std::unique_ptr<foo>` in the pair.

Comment: AH yes, sorry. How did I miss that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When "find" searches in a vector, it will look at the value of the entry in the vector, and match that with what you are searching for. So, it will use whatever "equal" function that is provided by the find, or "operator==" if there is no function provided to find.

Since in this case, you are just comparing the int value in the pair with your expected value, the  `unique_ptr<foo>` will not be dereferenced (and thus data pointed to by `unique_ptr<foo>` will not enter the cache).

Answer (score 0):

strictly speaking you don't... nowadays I see no reason why this loop should prefetch smth from stored pointer. from machine's point of view you've iterated over a contiguous memory block full of ints and pointer, where only ints are accessed... no reason to prefetch pointers content...
but, maybe later in you code (quite near `find_if`) there is another loop which would dereference that pointers, so damn smart compiler could decide to insert a fetch instructions in a first loop (this wouldn't affect `find_if` anyway, so it could!)... we don't know -- it is compiler + optimization-options + architecture depended... we even don't know that next Intel's BlahBlahBridge won't do it w/o any compiler instructions...